# Showing selection on 5 star rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to configure a 5 start rating system.
I have the css/html ready to display the stars.
What i need is when a user selects a star it should show it as selected currently it does not show.I will be using JS/Jquery/HTML or CSS.

Below is my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>5 star Rating!</title>
  <style>
    .rating {
      unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
      direction: rtl;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .rating>span {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      /*width: 1.1em;*/
    }
    
    .rating>span:hover,
    .rating>span:hover~span {
      color: transparent;
    }
    
    .rating>span:hover:before,
    .rating>span:hover~span:before {
      content: "\2605";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      color: gold;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    span {
      font-size: 120px;
      color: #f5f5f5;
      text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #000;
    }
    
    body {
      background-image: url('https://sap.quickbase.com/up/biv7kj2ug/g/rh/eh/va/canvas-ptrn.jpg');
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      background-color: #55A0EF;
      height: 175px;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0.7;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #000;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    h1 {
      text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px #000, 1px 1px 0px #fff;
      color: #535353;
      font-family: Arial Narrow, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 100px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: -5px;
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>Star Rating</h1><br />
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="rating">
        <span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i suggest you clean up your code.. it is EXTREMELY messy.

Comment: you can try like this http://rog.ie/blog/css-star-rater  and     http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/w9S9P/

Comment: @K.B.M thanks but can you help me on the same code I have mentioned here.I mean what should be changed in the code itself.

Comment: What if I want to select 0 stars i.e first I selected 2 stars and then want to make it to 0.Its not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I applied the code of @K.B.M. See demo:

```js
$('.star').on('click', function(){
    $('.star').addClass('selected');
    var count = $(this).attr('name'); 
    for (var i=0; i<count-1; i++){        
        $('.star').eq(i).removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

```css
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: center;
}
.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  /*width: 1.1em;*/
}
.rating > span:hover,
.rating > span:hover ~ span {
  color: transparent;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
   left: 0; 
   color: gold;
   cursor: pointer;
}

span {
    font-size:120px;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #000;
}


body { 
    background-image: url('https://sap.quickbase.com/up/biv7kj2ug/g/rh/eh/va/canvas-ptrn.jpg');
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #55A0EF;
    height:175px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #000;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

h1 {
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px #000, 1px 1px 0px #fff;
    color: #535353;
    font-family: Arial Narrow, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -5px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.selected{color:gold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<center>
<h1>Star Rating</h1><br />
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="rating">
<span class="star" name="1">&#9733;</span> 
<span class="star" name="2">&#9733;</span> 
<span class="star" name="3">&#9733;</span> 
<span class="star" name="4">&#9733;</span> 
<span class="star" name="5">&#9733;</span> 
</div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
```

added this css

```
.selected{color:gold;}
```

and the javascript

```
$('.star').on('click', function(){
        $('.star').addClass('selected');
        var count = $(this).attr('name'); 
        for (var i=0; i<count-1; i++){        
            $('.star').eq(i).removeClass('selected');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I didnt gave this as answer becoz its going in reverse order :) need to change js code here :)

Comment: check it again, fixed it now